# How to output array from prepared pdo

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write a prepared statement which gathers data from a set of bound fields and output them to an array variable called `$data`.

```
global $db;
$user_id = (int)$user_id;
$fields = 'field1, field2, field3';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT :fields FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->bindValue(':fields', $fields);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchall();

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = array(
        'field1' => $row['field1'], 
        'field2' => $row['field2'], 
        'field3' => $row['field3']
    );
}

print_r($data);
```

However all is am getting is...

```
Notice: Undefined index: field1 in C:\\\\\\.php on line #
Notice: Undefined index: field2 in C:\\\\\\.php on line #
Notice: Undefined index: field3 in C:\\\\\\.php on line #
Array ( [field1] => [field2] => [field3] => )
```

And here is the vardump (Note, the code here is a replica of my code.. the dump is a copy and post with field names removed.)

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["field1, field2, field3"]=> string(22) "field1, field2, field3" [0]=> string(22) "field1, field2, field3" } } Array ( [field1] => [field2] => [field3] => )
```

This is probably very simple.. but I am at that point where I'm learning from my mistakes.

Also, I would like to change the `$field` variable from a string to an array. How could I bind an array which processes every piece of data and then outputs it into the `$data` array?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($result);` ?

Comment: Are the fields empty?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran interesting, i will certainly use that to debug in the future! Updated the post !

Comment: You need to execute as an `array()` not the way you're doing it now.

Comment: @Jack Oops, yes they will be. This piece of code is a replica with all crucial information removed. I've updated it to reflect my code which does have a database!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I understand that I'm doing it wrong. That's why I'm posting here.

Comment: You need to use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC if you want to use the field names as the keys

Comment: And none of the answers given below have solved it? @user2950370

Comment: @Fred-ii- They have! Just taking some time understanding them :-)

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution @user2950370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the method's named `fetchAll`, which is irrelevant in this case because you're using an ID which might result in one returned row and not more. In this case, you should be using `fetch` to retrieve the result. Also you have to state in what form you want the array to be fetched. Do you want an associative array (in this case you do), numeric? Then inside the `fetch` method you need to specify one of the PDO constants to specify the array type (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`).

There is also no need to bind strings like you did, it's safe to put the field names directly in the query.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM users WHERE user_id = 1");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$data = array(
    'field1' => $row['field1'], 
    'field2' => $row['field2'], 
    'field3' => $row['field3']
);

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that user_id is the primary key you don't need a foreach loop there

```
$fields = 'field1, field2, field3';
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT $fields FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array(1));
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

$data = array(
    'field1' => $result['field1'], 
    'field2' => $result['field2'], 
    'field3' => $result['field3']
);

print_r($data);
```

I mean, why would you have a user_id if two users can have the same id

Comment: I've updated the original post to reflect a few inconsistencies between mine and this replica. A variable $user_id is the primary key.

A little question about your code. Is this code safe from sql injection? I thought that code inserted into the query was safer if it went through bindValue(). Maybe pdo statement prepare() does the job? thanks

Comment: It's safe, my statement is same as yours but if you want to specify type so much I'd recommend `$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` or since user_id is an integer you can just prepare statement as above and execute as `$stmt->execute(array(intval($user_id)))` but well, yo got the idea

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**You need to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` if you want to use the field names as the keys**

I don't know the exact format you're trying to output, but each time that foreach loop loops, you overwrite the $data array.

If you're only pulling one record (which is what it looks like) you don't need to loop, and can just output the array.

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $data = array(
        'field1' => $result['field1'], 
        'field2' => $result['field2'], 
        'field3' => $result['field3']
    );

print_r($data);
```

Comment: Oops, the code posted on here is a replica. I forgot to post $data[], rather than $data. Anyways working through these replies at the moment, thanks for your input :-)